# Value Keeps Returning Early

Tags: ruby, return-value, primes

I'm writing a method that keeps returning a value early. I know how to write in a different way, but I would like to understand why writing it this way keeps returning the wrong value. I'm trying to get the "nth" prime number, and the below method seemingly works, and there're no errors, but it keeps returning 1. In the below, I've even used the "p" function to make sure that count and int is incrementing each time is found, but for whatever reason, the return value I'm getting is 1, or whatever value I call the upto method on. Any pointers or explanation about why this keeps happening would be very much welcome.

```
def primeMover(num)
    count = 0  
    1.upto(num) do |int|
      return int if count == num
      count += 1 if is_prime?(int)
    end          
end

def is_prime?(number)  
  return false if number < 2
  2.upto(Math.sqrt(number)) { |divisor| return false if number % divisor == 0 }  
  return true 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it keeps returning 1.

1. upto() is defined to return the left hand side.
2. In general, a method returns the *value* of the last statement that was executed--return statements are not required.

The last statement in primeMover() is the method call `1.upto()`. Note that a block is similar to a method definition, and the block is actually sent to the upto() method as an argument, something like this:

```
 1.upto(3, proc{|int| ...})
```

Therefore, if upto() runs to completion the return value of    primeMover() will be whatever upto() returns.

Even if `isprime?()` returns true every time, `return int` will never execute:

```
def primeMover(num)
    count = 0  

    1.upto(num) do |int|
      return int if count == num
      count += 1   #mimicking is_prime()? returning true every time
    end          
end

result = primeMover(3)
puts result

--output:--
1
```

That's because you increment count too late:

```
def primeMover(num)
    count = 0  
    puts "num = #{num}"

    1.upto(num) do |int|
      puts int

      return int if count == num
      puts "int = #{int}, count = #{count}"

      count += 1 
      puts count

      puts '-' * 10
    end          
end

result = primeMover(3)
puts '=' * 10
puts result

--output:--
num = 3
1
int = 1, count = 0
1
----------
2
int = 2, count = 1
2
----------
3
int = 3, count = 2
3
----------
==========
1
```

Comment: Yeah, and the "early return" is never actually reached because you are only searching from 1 to N for the Nth prime, and the Nth prime will usually be a lot bigger than N.  You should search a larger space.  You should probably use an infinite loop instead of using upto.